# FFMPEG Bash Script incorrectly using cover metadata instead of images

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, script, shell-script, sh

I'm trying to run a script that that is meant to convert a folder of images and a folder of audio into videos however it's pulling the metadata of the album art instead.
Looking for a correction please:

```
for file in *.aac; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -vcodec copy "${file%aac}jpg"
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i  "${file%aac}jpg" -i "$file" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -b:a 320k -shortest "${file%aac}mp4"
done
```